# Is it ok to skip delete for a dynamically-allocated static member variable?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, static-members, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it fine to define a static member variable as a newed object and never delete it? For example

```
class A
{
    static vector<BaseClass*> p;
};

vector<BaseClass*> A::p = vector<BaseClass*>{new DerivedClassA, ...};
```

I think there is no memory leakage problem because p is static, its life cycle is over the whole program and its memory will be released by the operating system when the program is terminated. Its memory behavior seems almost similar to the following

```
class A
{
    static vector<unique_ptr<BaseClass>> p;
};

vector<unique_ptr<BaseClass>> A::p = ...;
```

But I am not sure if I am right or not.

Comment: there is no need to use new, just put int on stack

Comment: I use int as an example only.

Comment: I also mean int as an example only

Comment: Thank. Modified my question to make it more meaningful.

Comment: @dlf yes. I corrected it.

Comment: Side note: if you `new`, you are putting the object on the heap. If you don't, you are putting it in the `.data` section. Besides trivial differences such as the size of your `.data` section, or the extra node in the malloc's linked list, there is essentially no difference. If you plan on making the object static (read global), I would go with the simpler version, i.e. don't use `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that even through the memory occupied by the `BaseClass` objects will be freed by the OS, `~BaseClass()` will not be called. This could cause issues if these destructors do something important. But even if they don't, I still wouldn't recommend this. It will look fishy to anyone reading your code, and further, if you're using an IDE like Visual Studio that warns (can warn) you about memory leaks at shutdown, this sort of thing will make it yell at you. And if you get used to ignoring it when it yells at you, you'll miss a real problem eventually.